# ZF2 count rows with hydrator

Tags: count, zend-framework2

Is there a correct way to count the rows of a table in Zend Framework 2 while using an hydrator ?

I have tried the following:

```
$result = $this->select();
return $result->count();
```

but that's a bad way of achieving it, so I've tried

```
return $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select) {
    $select->columns(array('num' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(1)')));
});
```

but the problem is that I am using an hydrator, so any field that's not matched in the Module configuration is simply dropped from the resource.

Is there a clean way of retrieving the number of rows while using an hydrator ? I'd like to avoid doing something like this:

```
$select->columns(array('id' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(1)')))
```

Comment: Using `tableGateway` for retrieving one field feels like an overkill to me. Hydrators are supposed to set data on object and in that particular case it would mean that you'd have an object which sole responsibility is to hold the count. Maybe just calling `query` from the db adapter would do?

Comment: the problem is that calling a query just break all "transparency" in case of evolving SGDB (passing from mysql to something bigger like sqlsrv or oracle)